# Prometheus - CPU utilization per POD per Node

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, cpu, promql

I am trying to extract CPU usage per POD per node using Prometheus. I am currently using the following query:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{kubernetes_io_hostname="$host",container!="",namespace=~"default"}[1m]))
/ sum (machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"$host"}) * 100
```

However, this provides the CPU usage per node by all PODs. I tried grouping labels with the below:

```
sum (sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{kubernetes_io_hostname="$host",container!="",namespace=~"default"}[2m]))
/ on (pod) group_left (kubernetes_io_hostname) (machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname="$host"})) * 100
```

This gives me a similar output to 1st query in terms of percentage but it is still not separating it by POD.

Any suggestion how to get the correct value?

Comment: Does `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` even have `pod` label?

Comment: If yes, you caould try something like `sum by (pod) (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{kubernetes_io_hostname="$host",container!="",namespace=~"default"}[1m])) / on() sum (machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"$host"}) * 100`

Comment: @markalex, thank you for the response. Yeap, `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` does have the `pod` label. I tried the suggested solution but I've got an error that **execution: multiple matches for labels: many-to-one matching must be explicit (group_left/group_right)**

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Add `group_left()` between `on() ` and `sum( ...`. Also, please understand that all I can help here is to construct query; I don't have knowledge of what this metrics mean and if they are correct one to get values that you desire/

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a solution to this, @markalex has provided the answer

```
sum by (pod) (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{kubernetes_io_hostname="$host",container!="",namespace=~"default"}[1m])) 
 / on() group_left() sum (machine_cpu_cores{kubernetes_io_hostname=~"$host"})
 * 100
```